# Can not find the Homebrew in the terminal

Tags: terminal, homebrew

But in the Mac OS, I use `brew` to install the `setuptools`:

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ brew install -y setuptools
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> New Formulae
adr-tools                                goad
allure                                   grakn
angular-cli                              iamy                                   zyre
get_iplayer
==> Updated Formulae
aalib                      gspell                     opencore-amr
......
gsl                        opencoarrays
==> Renamed Formulae
grunt -> grunt-cli
==> Deleted Formulae
autotrace  blucat     dvtm       libgc      libtess2   snescom    xplanetfx

Error: No available formula with the name "setuptools" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I want to find the `Homebrew`, so I use:

```
whereis homebrew
whereis Homebrew
whereis brew
```

All find nothing. how to know the homebrew location, why use the `whereis` can not find it?

Comment: `type -p brew` will show the path to `brew`, but probably doesn't solve your problem. Did you run `brew doctor` yet?

Answer (score -1):

you should try locate Homebrew or locate homebrew.  The find command will help too.

type:  locate homebrew
or:    locate Homebrew